# onclick is not called (search-box-with-suggestions-dropdown)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use this code:
[search with suggestions](http://cssdeck.com/labs/search-box-with-suggestions-dropdown)

Only one thing I am changing there is that I am adding `onclick="alert('test');" in every

```
    <li><a href="index.html" onclick="alert('test');">Search Result #1<br /><span>Description</span></a></li>`
```

To make list with search. What I need more is to make it autocomplete input while one of suggestions is cliked. I dont know why it is not working, onclick is not called. I found that if I comment out this line:

```
    .search .results {
        //display: none;
    . . .
```

then on click works normally, but of course results are shown before searching is started...

Could you please help me with that problem or point another sample which I could rely on?

sample with alert: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZxrxN

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you be more specific to the problem ? Also please post more code to let us analyze how much you have done so far and where exactly are you stuck

Comment: Check the link I have posted. `<ul class="results" >
    <li><a href="index.html" onclick="alert('it is not called');>Search Result #1<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>`

There is code that I am using, `href` and `onclick` (which I am adding) doesnt work.

Comment: because focus is lost when you click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is you are showing the items with focus on the input. When you click the focus is lost so the list is hidden.

First option is to use `onmousedown` instead of `onclick` and leave the code as is. The mousedown event fires before the focus is lost.

Your second option is to update the rule so when hovered the menu does not hide. With this you can keep it as click.

```
.search input:focus + .results,
.search .results:hover { 
    display: block 
}
```